# iOS - App Freeze When I Fetch Request Deadlock

Tags: ios, core-data, request, freeze

Hi good people I'm trying to prevent the freezing with

```
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{ CODE });
```

but I don't know how to use function.. I don't know where to put the managedObjectContext and how to use this dispatch_async my code is:

```
- (void)updateFacebookFriendsHighScore{
    NSFetchRequest *requestche =[NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Time"];
    [requestche setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
    NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"timeid==1"];
    requestche.predicate=predicate;
    NSArray *getIDTime = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:requestche error:nil];
    NSString *getTheTime = [[getIDTime valueForKey:@"time"] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    NSNumber *timeInInt = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: [getTheTime intValue]];
    int timeFromDB = [timeInInt intValue];
    timeFromDB = timeFromDB + 509;
    int timeNow = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    if(timeNow > timeFromDB){
        NSFetchRequest *updateHighScoreRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Friends"];
        [updateHighScoreRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
        NSArray *friendsToUpdate = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:updateHighScoreRequest error:nil];
        for(NSArray *friendId in friendsToUpdate){
            NSString *getFriendId = [friendId valueForKey:@"fbid"] ;
            NSString *siteURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.example.com/example.php?fbid=%@", getFriendId];
            NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:siteURL]];
            [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                NSString *resultsFromDB = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSNumber *theScoreForUpdate = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[resultsFromDB intValue]];
                NSFetchRequest *updateTheHighScoreRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Friends"];
                NSPredicate *updateTheHighScorePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fbid==%@",getFriendId];
                updateTheHighScoreRequest.predicate=updateTheHighScorePredicate;
                Friends *setScore = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:updateTheHighScoreRequest error:nil] lastObject];
                NSLog(@"%@", setScore);
                [setScore setValue:theScoreForUpdate forKey:@"score"];
                [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
                data = nil;
                resultsFromDB = nil;
                theScoreForUpdate = nil;
                setScore = nil;
         }];
        updateHighScoreRequest = nil;
        }
    }
    requestche = nil;
}
```

This code gets the time from database and update the highscore after 509 seconds from the CD result and when I run this request my app freeze ( DEADLOCK ).
I am from Bulgaria and I'm trying to learn Objective C. Here we don't have schools for this our country is very bad in all instance and Bulgaria is last in Europe Union...
Can some serious and good person help me with my code or explane how works everything in Objective C or only help me with this ?

Comment: Are you using threads in your application? If you have an understanding of what they are?

Comment: Do you have skype to help me there and I will post the answer here and I will explain to people which don't know like me :)
My skype is: smoka_bogdan

Comment: Sorry not right now, I am at office. May be later at some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. To keep the application as simple as possible, never take the Core data code out of the main thread i.e. any thing related to self.managedObjectContext such as save or executing fetch requests. It is because Core data is not thread safe and you will have to device a strategy to handle that. I am assuming that your application is straight forward and you don't need such a strategy. So, please try to keep it as simple as possible and always perform the core data operations (save, execute) on main thread.  `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ code });` will execute it on main thread.

```
-(void) updateFacebookFriendsHighScore
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        NSFetchRequest *requestche =[NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Time"];
        [requestche setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
        NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"timeid==1"];
        requestche.predicate=predicate;
        NSArray *getIDTime = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:requestche error:nil];
        NSString *getTheTime = [[getIDTime valueForKey:@"time"] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
        NSNumber *timeInInt = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: [getTheTime intValue]];
        int timeFromDB = [timeInInt intValue];
        timeFromDB = timeFromDB + 509;
        int timeNow = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
        if(timeNow > timeFromDB){
            NSFetchRequest *updateHighScoreRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Friends"];
            [updateHighScoreRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
            NSArray *friendsToUpdate = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:updateHighScoreRequest error:nil];
            for(NSArray *friendId in friendsToUpdate){
                NSString *getFriendId = [friendId valueForKey:@"fbid"] ;
                NSString *siteURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.example.com/example.php?fbid=%@", getFriendId];
                NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:siteURL]];
                [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                    NSString *resultsFromDB = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                    NSNumber *theScoreForUpdate = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[resultsFromDB intValue]];
                    NSFetchRequest *updateTheHighScoreRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Friends"];
                    NSPredicate *updateTheHighScorePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fbid==%@",getFriendId];
                    updateTheHighScoreRequest.predicate=updateTheHighScorePredicate;
                    Friends *setScore = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:updateTheHighScoreRequest error:nil] lastObject];
                    NSLog(@"%@", setScore);
                    [setScore setValue:theScoreForUpdate forKey:@"score"];
                    [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
                    data = nil;
                    resultsFromDB = nil;
                    theScoreForUpdate = nil;
                    setScore = nil;
                }];
                updateHighScoreRequest = nil;
            }
        }
        requestche = nil;

    });
}
```

Comment: Hmm. I think than you have some thread that is executing code on core data. Is there any way you can share your code so that i can look at it, if it is possible?

Comment: http://bbogdanov.us/hilo/index.txt here mate :)
Please give an email or some contact form.
I want to contact you personally :)
http://facebook.com/bbogdanov

Comment: I have sent you message on fb. I will check your code in an hour or so. I am a little busy right now.

Comment: Check for any piece of code that is using self.managedObjectContext and add the code block in to dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ code }); I have checked the code but it is hard to tell anything without executing it, and if I could get the project in zip form then it will be easy to just run and test it.

Comment: Can you please point me out the steps which will cause the freeze? I have been testing it and it has not freeze yet.

Comment: When you lose the game it opens you GOVC and the cause of freeze is 
            [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                NSString *resultsFromDB = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];....

WHEN MAKES THIS REQUEST TO UPDATE FRIENDS HIGH SCORE IT FREEZE

Comment: ok, I was checking it on the simulator. Try by deleting the app from device, then in Xcode go to Product->Clean. Then install again and if see if it still stuck.

Comment: Watch the code ot will stuck after 509 seconds after facebook connect because
 timeFromDB = timeFromDB + 509;
this code will be run after 509 seconds :) 
On simulator also stucksa after 509 seconds